# Identify sound clip in a wav file using Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am working on a personal project. Basically I have a collection of small sound clips, like a clap or a beep noise. I want to create a program that listens for the sounds via a mic or some form of audio input, and when I play sound clip it should identify that clip.

I have tried looking into this myself and have found this article.
http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/

I tried replicating it, but I have found that it doesn't work as expected. I am guessing the sound clips I am using to create my hash from are too small to create enough values to compare.

Wondering if there any well know programs or algorithms that are capable of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Dan Ellis' [slides](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/e4896/lectures/E4896-L13.pdf) are probably a good start. They explain the principal task of audio fingerprinting and the two best known approaches:

- The Shazam algorithm by A. Wang ([paper](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf))
- The Philips (now Gracenote) algorithm by Haitsma/Kalker ([paper](http://www.nhchau.com/files/AudioFingerprint-02-FP04-2.pdf))

As you have already tried the landmark (Shazam) approach, perhaps it's worth your time to fiddle around with the stream-based approach. Since your queries are very short, you might also want to tweak the analysis frame length and overlap. Shorter frames and greater overlap may improve your results for very short samples. If you want to delve even deeper into the Haitsma/Kalker algorithm, you might also be interested in this unfortunately paywalled [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TMM.2014.2318517) (by me).